# Why if condition executes even when the control variable is False?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have code that checks if a variable is an empty string or not.
If it is, then the `if` statement executes. However, even when the string is not empty (data exists), it still executes the if statement.

Code I use (ripped off my big program so lot of unknown vars):

```py
print(bytes(read_config.read(), encoding='utf-8').decode(encoding='utf-8') == "")
if bytes(read_config.read(), encoding='utf-8').decode(encoding='utf-8') == "":
    print("in if")
    with open(path, "w") as writeData: writeData.write(data)
    updateRead =  open(path, "r")
    read_config = updateRead
    print("wrote data")
```

Basically, I read a text file, and if the data is an empty string it should write the given data. If the data from the file is *not* an empty string it should use the statement below the `if` statement (didn't include here).

In the `print` statement, it prints out False Boolean. But it *still* goes to the `if` statement and uses the code there which resets the data. And yes, I used `updateRead` without the `with` statement on purpose.

I tried this, and lot others, and I expected the statement followed by the if statement to be executed if the data is not empty, however, still didn't work.

Comment: start by using proper indentation of the code

Comment: Bruh stackoverflow just messes the indentation up every time I fix. will try again

Comment: For proper code blocks put `\`\`\`python` at the beginning of its own line, then paste your python code block next, then put `\`\`\`` at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: `bytes(read_config.read(), encoding='utf-8').decode(encoding='utf-8')`is just an expensive and confusing way of writing `read_config.read()`.

Comment: don't read the file to check if it's empty use `if not os.path.getsize(name_of_the_file):` as a test. If the size is 0 it enters. And in your case, lazy copy paste tripped you. Never copy paste when you can avoid it

Comment: Yeah @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I tried that for debugging purposes. Now my code is up there, new code section, without the bytes decoding and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file can only be read once. When you call `read_config.read()` in the `print` call that reads the entire file. Calling it again in the `if` statement will return an empty string since the file's already been read.

If you want to print what's been read for debugging purposes you'll need to save it in a variable so you don't call `read()` twice.

```
file_contents = bytes(read_config.read(), encoding='utf-8').decode(encoding='utf-8')
if file_contents == "":
    print("in if")
    with open(path, "w") as writeData: writeData.write(data)
    updateRead =  open(path, "r")
    read_config = updateRead
    print("wrote data")
```

Comment: I would use `if not file_contents`, which would avoid to even decode the contents of the file because it tests for null bytes

Comment: Thanks bro, it was the answer, reading a file can only be done once? I now know that
Thank you for the info, and the answer, now it works!